# How do I include and scale on-image-TikZ-drawings made by the standalone class?

Tags: graphics, conversion, scaling, tikz-external, standalone

I am building several on image TikZ drawings. In detail: I am having PDFs of technical drawings, I crop the white margins, overlay nodes and some arrows and compile them. The result should give me a nice PDF and PNG for further using and the TEX file shall be included in various bigger TeX documents.

I wonder, what is the best way for doing this especially for the scaling. The labels (nodes) should always have the current document font size, the vectors (arrows) should have the same line-width all over the document.

When and where should I scale? In my MWE I am letting the PDF on original size, put the nodes with relative coordinates and insert it with `\includestandalone` which results in down scaled labels.

I would like to get some advice how to do this for several pictures and a big bandwidth of results for different uses.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includestandalone[width=0.9\linewidth]{subfiles/TopView}
\caption{Top view}\label{fig:topView}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The file I want to insert could look e. g. like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, fp, tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections, arrows, fixedpointarithmetic, decorations.markings}
\graphicspath{../images/}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,line cap=round]
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{./images/3fan_AUTOCAD_0009.pdf}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
            \node at (0.854,0.855) [rotate=-40]{$\vartheta^\prime$};
            \node at (0.19,0.27) [rotate=40]{$f$};
            \node at (0.055,0.605) [rotate=30]{$\delta$};
            \node at (0.53,0.63) [rotate=40]{$R$};
            \node at (0.15,0.2) [rotate=-40]{$l_\mathrm{c}$};
            \draw[-latex, black] (0.8,0.1) -- (0.8,0.3) node[pos = .5, above, rotate = 90]{$\vec{u}$};
            \draw[-latex, blue] (0.1,0.8) -- (0.3,0.8) node[pos = .5, above, rotate = 0]{$\vec{c}_\mathrm{m}$};
    \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Here you can find the PDF: [PDF-Upload](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/520136/3fan_AUTOCAD_0009.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this awnser grew slowly lets start with the result, the same image once scaled to `.3\linewidth` and once scaled to `\linewidth`. The first section talks about the idea while the implementation is at the very bottom.

[image: Result]

**Source:**
image.tikz is at the bottom of this post.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
%\includestandalone[width=0.9\linewidth]{subfiles/TopView}
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{image}
\caption{Top view}\label{fig:topView}
\end{figure}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}
\end{document}
```

---

There is a package [`tikzscale`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzscale/tikzscale.pdf), which does most of waht you ask, from the documentation:

> So although the original tikzpicture itself has the width of a
>   complete line, it gets proportionally scaled down to half the width
>   while being loaded from the \includegraphics command. Neither the
>   line’s thickness nor the text center are scaled, [...]

If you use your graphics in documents with different font sizes though, be aware that the units `em` and `ex` change, thus their use might get you unwanted results if you mix them with absolute units.

I usually have one file with the headers and the [`preview` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/preview), that I use to render the image standalone. I use input to include the different images in that file.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     %input encoding

\usetikzlibrary{...}

\begin{document} 
  \input{image1} 
  %\input{image2}
\end{document}
```

So far I have not come arround to use tikz externalize which would leave you with pdfs automatically and it is supported by `tikzscale`. This might make my preview wrapper unnecessary.

Note that you do need to render the tikz files for every document you scale them in, since you don't want to scale the font/linewidths.

---

### Scaling

Regarding OPs comment: Scaling as you requested can not work from prerenders, since in a image file all pixels are equal, there is no difference between fonts/linewidth and linelength. The only option to rescale tikz images and to keep fontsize/linesizes I know of is `tikzscale`. Tikzscale has some very strict requirements, one being that the image is in a file with the extension `.tikz`. Thus I renamed the second file to end in `tikz`. I then change your main file to this:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
%\includestandalone[width=0.9\linewidth]{subfiles/TopView}
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{image}
\caption{Top view}\label{fig:topView}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you now run this you will get an error along the lines: `Request to scale an unscalable image`.

This comes from the fact that you image IS unscalable. Your image is based on a node with an `includegraphics`. `tikzscale` only scales tikz coordinates. You then place nodes at the edges of the unscalable node holding text (text may not scale so these dont scale either).

So how does one obtain a scalable image?

add this as the last line of your picture: `\node at(2,2) {scaler};`

You can try this method with different tikzpictures, then it should work.

Or as a workarround: Place two coordinates as coornerpoints of a rectangle (best with mesurement in an absolute mesure like `cm`), calculate the size of this and use `scalebox` to include the pdf. This way if tikzscale shifts the coordinates your included pdf scales. Therefore your image is now scalable.

---

here is an implementation of a workarround, It works as follows:
with `\pgfgettransformentries` we obtain the current scale matrix and use the `x` or `y-scale` to scale the included image by using graphicx `scale` option by using `\includegraphics[scale=\a]{image2.pdf}};`. Therefore the image size changes and the whole thing can be scaled.

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, fp, tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections, arrows, fixedpointarithmetic, decorations.markings}
\graphicspath{../images/}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,line cap=round]
\pgfgettransformentries{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}{\xtrans}{\ytrans}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=\a]{image2.pdf}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
            \node at (0.854,0.855) [rotate=-40]{$\vartheta^\prime$};
            \node at (0.19,0.27) [rotate=40]{$f$};
            \node at (0.055,0.605) [rotate=30]{$\delta$};
            \node at (0.53,0.63) [rotate=40]{$R$};
            \node at (0.15,0.2) [rotate=-40]{$l_\mathrm{c}$};
            \draw[-latex, black] (0.8,0.1) -- (0.8,0.3) node[pos = .5, above, rotate = 90]{$\vec{u}$};
            \draw[-latex, blue] (0.1,0.8) -- (0.3,0.8) node[pos = .5, above, rotate = 0]{$\vec{c}_\mathrm{m}$};
    \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in your MWE there is no scaling done at all. How would you do it, if you want a png and an inserted image in a two and one columns document having fontsize and linewidth (and of course positioning) equal in all three documents? Do I scale the original file already to get my PNG, or should I export the picture after compiling it in the main doc? I would like to see, how you would treat my given example.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: see the update. P.S.: You did not include the pdf in the example, neither its dimensions.

Comment: the reason for the comments is because we prefer to post working compilable solutions rather than *way of working* answers.

Comment: I added my PDF to the OP. I will got through your workaround tomorrow. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I tried getting the length of a vector with `veclen`but this is scaled as well. If everything else works I suggest you ask how you can read the value of the transformation matrix to pass this into the `includegraphics` command. Thats why I have no mwe for the last part yet.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I made another update, It now works for your image, if you add two modifications. See the bottom of the post.

Comment: @percusse: after I figured out how to access the scaleing factor to use it in the `includegraphics` command I now have a mwe, I hope this lives up to the sites standards.

Comment: @ted Thanks for your efforts. The scaled inclusion is working now. Great. But still I am seeing two problems here. For further distribution of the pictures I would like to generate one perfectly scaled PDF and PNG. The `[scale=\a]` takes away the possibility to scale my standalone image. The `.tikz` file name gives a `LaTeX Error: File 'TopView.tex' not found`.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: What do you mean with `takes away the possibility to scale your stand alone image`, I do not see any reason why `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=...]` should not work anymore. And for the `.tikz` filename, you get that error when you try what? (If you are trying to compile a `.tikz` file from a tex IDE make sure it uses `currentfilenmae with extension` instead of `currentBaseFilename +'.tex'` (i.e. `?me` instead of  `%.tex` for texstudio)

Comment: ah, I thought I have to scale at `\includegraphics{...`. That works perfect. I added `%nm` to my compilation arguments and that works for the `.tikz`-file. But I have to remove it again, when I want to compile the whole document.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: what tool are you using to compile your tex files? Note that I `replaced` what I had before (you said you added).

Comment: TeXnicCenter. `-max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm" lualatex.exe` for the main doc. `%nm -enable-write18 -max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm" lualatex.exe` for my `.tikz` files. PNG-conversion doesn't work till now, but I did another question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125151/why-does-the-standalone-package-give-the-conversion-error-shell-escape-disabled#comment282561_125151.